# Получение массива данных из Node.js в AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

Вместо переданного массива данных из Node.js в AngularJS, в тег выводит текст самой HTML страницы.

База данных, из которой получаю данные:

```
var pg = require("pg");
var rest;

var pool = new pg.Pool({
    host:"***",
    port:"***",
    user:"***",
    password:"****",
    database:"***"
});

pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    if (err)
        console.log("connect " + err.toString());
    else
        client.query('SELECT *' +
            'FROM public."GeneralInfo";', function(err, result) {

            if (err)
                console.log("query " + err.toString());
            else {
                console.log(result.rows[0]);
                rest = result.rows[0];
            }
            done();
        });
});
pool.end();

module.exports.res = rest;
```

Отсылаю на клиент данные:

```
var express = require('express');
var connectResult = require('./ConnectDB/connect');

app.get("/",function (req,res) {
    console.log(connectResult);
    res.send(connectResult);
});
```

Пытаюсь получить данные на клиенте

```
var controller = function ($scope,$http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080").then (function (response) {
        console.log("I get date with DB");
        console.log(response);
        $scope.dateWithDb = response;
    },function (res) {console.log(res.toString()) });
}
angular.module("DB",[]).controller("controller",controller);
```

HTML страница:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app = DB>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="controller">
    <h1>{{dateWithDb}}</h1>
    <script src="./angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascripts/controllerInfo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

В итоге получаю такой текст:

`{"data": "<! DOCTYPE html> \ r \ n <html lang = \" en \ "ng-app = DB> \ r \ n <head> \ r \ n <meta charset = \" UTF-8 \ "> \ r \ n <title> Заголовок </ title> \ r \ n </ head> \ r \ n <body ng-controller = \" controller \ "> \ r \ n <h1> {{date. result}} </ h1> \ r \ n <h2> {{dateWithDb}} </ h2> \ r \ n <script src = \ "./ angular / angular.min.js \"> </ script> \ r \ n <script src = \ "./ javascripts / controllerInfo.js \"> </ script> \ r \ n \ r \ n </ body> \ r \ n \ r \ n </ html> "," статус ": 200," конфигурация ": {" метод ":" GET " "transformRequest": [пустой] "transformResponse": [нуль], "jsonpCallbackParam": "Обратный вызов", "URL":" HTTP: / / локальный: 8080" , "заголовки": { "Accept":»application / json, text / plain, * / * "}}," statusText ":" OK "," xhrStatus ":" complete "}`

А Должен =  Иван Иванович Иванов Хороший Человек парам пам пам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это потому, что фронтенд и бакенд запускаются на одном сервере. Поэтому надо запускать бакенд отдельным сервером, который слушает запросы на другом порту:

```
app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('Сервер стартовал!');
});
```